# Parsing string into number

Tags: javascript

likeBar is an object and dislikeBar too,how to parse '107px' into number,i used parseFloat and others ,but i couldn't

```
        likeBar: {
            width: '107px'
        },
        dislikeBar: {
            width: '107px'
        }
```

Comment: You cannot convert the string `107px` into a number. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: parseInt('107px')

Comment: Closed too fast :( the answer is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/u5173mrv/3/)

Comment: @KennyMeyer Why not?

Comment: Obviously you cannot convert the string 107px  into a number, but one can certainly parse it to 'pull' the number 107 out of it!

Comment: @JosephDoggie true - but he said "Parsing string into number", no "parsing number from string"... well, I'm glad he found his answer.

Comment: @Kenny Meyer -- not everyone can handle grammar well

Answer (score 1):

```
Number(String(likebar.width).replace('px',''));
```